# Trying to Use Java VisualVM with Eclipse

Tags: java, eclipse, performance, stack, heap-memory

I want to use Java Visual VM. It's a software which helps you to check your Heap-Memory load. It also provides more functions. But those are not important for me.

The author of my beginner java book says that Java Visual VM is included in Java SE 9. I should be able to find the exe. in the bin folder of my JDK-folder. I tried to use this software and include it in Eclipse, by following the instructions of my book, but it does not work. I can not find the exe of Java Visual VM in my bin folder of my JDK. I have JDK 14 point something.

I hope someone can help me.

Comment: [Download it](https://visualvm.github.io/download.html)?

Answer (score 2):

From this link : https://visualvm.github.io/download.html

We learn it is no longer included starting java 9

> VisualVM has also been distributed in Oracle JDK 6~8 as Java VisualVM.
> It has been discontinued in Oracle JDK 9. See the Upgrading Java
> VisualVM page to learn how to upgrade to the latest VisualVM.

And this is also a download link, so please help yourself and get the tool ;)